# How can I move my footer to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

**URL:** http://test.getfamo.us/

**Problem:** I like when you scroll down how the header stays in place at the top off the page, howver with the footer I would prefer it if it only displayed when you scrolled all the way to the bottom of the page (so the position isnt fixed in place as it is now, but rather at the very bottom of the page).

**This is the CSS associated with the footer:**

```
#foot{
left:0px;
right:0px;
color:white;
position:fixed;
height:50px;
background-color:#444444;
width:100%;
margin-bottom:0px;
bottom:0px;
margin-right:0px;
z-index:103;
}

#foot a{
height:50px;
width:75px;
float:left;
color:white;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
line-height:25px;
 }

 #foot p{
position:absolute;
width:150px;
height:50px;
right:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-top:0px;
bottom:0px;
top:0px;
}
```

Thanks a lot guys! Hopefully its a simple fix.
Also if necessary full CSS available here: http://test.getfamo.us/css/

Comment: Are you joking? There are **loads** of these questions around. And you couldn't find [**this**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) link?

Comment: I want to know how to modify the existing code as well though, as I dont know what is still needed etc after updating it with the code in the link. Thanks for the link though, and sorry that I'm new to this stuff.I just thought it would be an easy answer for an experienced user! Sorry again.

Comment: Instead of `position:fixed` try `position:static`

Comment: Just an observation but you don't need units for zero values. 0 is the same no matter what unit you are using.

Comment: This stuff is called `sticky footer`. Google for it, there are lots of them. There's so much of this stuff that it even has a tag `[sticky-footer]` here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I gave you the link but if you are having trouble take a look at this. Using your code and the link I gave you we can create this.

### HTML:

```
<div class="page-wrap">
    <div id="fillspace"></div>
</div>
<div id="foot"></div>
```

### CSS:

```
/* Your code */
#foot {
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    color:white;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#444444;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    z-index:103;
}
#foot a {
    height:50px;
    width:75px;
    float:left;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:25px;
}
#foot p {
    position:absolute;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    right:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    top:0px;
}

/* New Code */
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.page-wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    /* equal to footer height */
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}
.page-wrap:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
}
#foot, .page-wrap:after {
    /* .push must be the same height as footer */
    height: 50px;
}
#fillspace {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

So put your code with the code in the link I gave you. Then we take away your `position: fixed` and set the correct heights of the footer to `#foot, .page-wrap:after` and `.page-wrap`. That's about it, all done. Take a look at the demo and play around with it.

**With content:**

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/VrXAz/)

**Without content:**

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/VrXAz/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much! Im looking into this now. The only problem im facing is I already have a lot of other content in my CSS: http://test.getfamo.us/css/screen.css so I cant just update it all to be like this without facing other errors, but thanks a lot for the clarification! Much appreciated.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, you should be able to update the footer without causing any other errors. Also if this is the correct answer could you accept it. If you are finding random errors post them back here and I will have a little look into it.